# Applescriptable mySQL client - low cost or free?

Tags: mysql, macos, applescript

Can anyone recommend a MySQL front end client or OS X that is AppleScriptable?  Preferably low cost or free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest just using the command-line mysql client and using the `do shell script` command in applescript to invoke it:

```
do shell script "mysql -e 'select * from customer'"
```